# Is there a easy way to map varchar2(1) ("1" or "0") to JPA boolean type

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa

I understand the default map is from oracle data type `NUMBER(1)` to JPA java `Boolean`, but not sure if there is default cast from `varchar2(1)` (it is either '1' or '0') to JPA java boolean? Is it the same way as mapping from NUMBER(1)?

Not sure the following idea is ok, referred from [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_pc_scos.html):

```
public class People{

    @ExternalValues({"true=1", "false=0"})
    @Type(String.class)
    private Boolean weird;

    ...
}
```

I am using OpenJPA 2.2.0 here. Thanks

Comment: Which JPA version are you using?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza OpenJPA 2.2.0, compliant to JPA 2.0 spec :)

Comment: FYI If you were using JPA 2.1 then you could just provide an AttributeConverter and map it however you feel. Since you're not then you'll have to find something specific to OpenJPA (non-portable).

Comment: The @ExternalValues route should work for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can use type casting in getter , setter methods and use String for you property datatype .

```
@Column(length=1 )
private String string;  

public Boolean getString() {
    return Boolean.valueOf(string) ;
}

public void setString(Boolean string) {
    this.string =  (string) ? "1" : "0";
}
```